# Why Can't I Call This Parent Function in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, inheritance

Parent function in ERC1155:

```
    function uri(uint256) external virtual view override returns (string memory) {
        return _uri;
    }
```

Attempted overriding function in my child contract:

```
    function uri(uint256 _id) external virtual view override(ERC1155) returns (string memory) {
        return Strings.strConcat(
            ERC1155.uri(),
            Address.toAsciiString(address(this)),
            "/",
            Strings.uint2str(_id),
            ".json"
        );
    }
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot call function via contract type name.
            ERC1155.uri(),
            ^-----------^
```

I'm doing approximately the same thing in the same file but it works:

```
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address operator,
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256[] memory ids,
        uint256[] memory amounts,
        bytes memory data
    )
        internal virtual override(ERC1155, ERC1155Pausable)
    {
        ERC1155Pausable._beforeTokenTransfer(operator, from, to, ids, amounts, data);
    }
```

That function is internal so it's different, but does that difference matter?

Using Solc 0.6.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
ERC1155.uri()
```

To this:

```
super.uri(_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel silly for missing this, but ultimately it wasn't the real problem. I updooted you but my karma's too low for it to count :-(

Comment: @Dobit: `Cannot call function via contract type name.` - it most certainly **WAS** the problem. Perhaps not the only one, as you've noted (and even as I noted in my own answer - see the missing `_id` that I added). But specifically **for this compilation error**, the problem was that you've used the contract name instead of `super`!

Comment: Both the contract name and super work, but I'll give you the answer because I did clearly get that part wrong and you informed me of it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the difference did matter. The reason it didn't work is because external functions cannot be called internally, and I was trying to call `uri` inside the child function overriding it. I changed its scope to `public` in both the parent and the child contract, and then it compiled fine (after I also applied Goodvibration's fix, which was necessary as well.)

Comment: This DOES NOT explain the compilation error given in your question - `Cannot call function via contract type name`, hence it is at best an incomplete answer!